# How to check if collection exists in MongoDB with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

Basically, I want to hide a **div** based on whether a collection exists or not. Does anyone know the simplest way to do so? I am using Mongoose and Express.js with Jade.

Comment: The question had been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13395041/nodejs-mongo-native-check-if-collection-exists-before-query Hope this helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to hit mongodb directly via the node.js native api you can use db.collectionNames():

> List existing collections
>
> List names
>
> Collections can be listed with collectionNames
>
> db.collectionNames(callback);
>
> callback gets two parameters - an error object (if error occured) and
>   an array of collection names as strings.
>
> Collection names also include database name, so a collection named
>   posts in a database blog will be listed as blog.posts.
>
> Additionally there’s system collections which should not be altered
>   without knowing exactly what you are doing, these sollections can be
>   identified with system prefix. For example posts.system.indexes.
>
> Example:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient   , format = require('util').format;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {

  if(err) throw err;   
  db.collectionNames(function(err, collections){
       console.log(collections);   
  }); 
});
```

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/collections.html

Comment: That method no longer exists since this migration:http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/meta/changes-from-1.0/

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
 db.system.namespaces.find( { name: dbName +'.' + collectionName } );
```

It contains entries for collections and indices, for existing collection it should return something like this:

```
{ "name" : "temp333.categories" }
```

To do it from mongoose you could define system.namespaces model and query.